# Постинг в вк через Api

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

В чем проблема? Не загружает картинку в пост
Заранее спасибо!

```
import os
import vk
import sys
import requests
import json

session = vk.AuthSession(app_id='...', user_login='...', user_password='...', scope='wall, messages, photos')
vk_api = vk.API(session, v='5.85')
groupID = '172896425'

upload_url = vk_api.photos.getWallUploadServer(group_id=groupID)['upload_url']

request = requests.post(upload_url, files={'photo': open('1.jpg', "rb")})
params = {'server': request.json()['server'],
          'photo': request.json()['photo'],
          'hash': request.json()['hash'],
          'group_id': groupID}

photo_id = vk_api.photos.saveWallPhoto(**params)[0]['id']

params = {'attachments': 'photo'+ groupID + '_'+ str(photo_id),
          'message': 'test',
          'owner_id': '-' + groupID,
          'from_group': '1'}
vk_api.wall.post(**params)
```

Comment: Какая ошибка вылезает?

Comment: Проверьте правильность поля attachments - зайдите на страницу с изображением в вк и посмотрите на ссылку - все ли так же как там у вас в программе

Comment: И нужны ли две звезды перед params - вы же не переменное количество аргументов передаете, а один - словарь со значениями

Comment: ошибку никакую не выдает и картинка в группе не появляется

Comment: Name "data" is not defined. Приведите полный код, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

В последнем блоке params не то id передавал

```
photo_id = data [0]['id']

params = {'attachments': 'photo'+ str(data [0]['owner_id']) + '_'+ str(photo_id),
          'message': 'test',
          'owner_id': '-' + groupID,
          'from_group': '1'}
```